# How to add <c:if> jstl within <form:option>

Tags: jsp

This is my data.jsp and when i deploy it works properley but when i trying to access this jsp through url. These are the jstl which i added to this jsp...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<html lang="en">
```

it gives me below exception.

```
Unterminated &lt;form:option tag
--------------------------------

<tbody>
     <tr>
         <c:forEach items="${data}" var="data">
           <td class="td-top td-left">
              <form:select class="selectpicker form-control select-di" path="eastOrder" id="east-order" isChanged="false">
                 <form:option value="1" <c:if test="${data.order == '1'}">selected="true"</c:if>>1</form:option>
                 <form:option value="2" <c:if test="${data.order == '2'}">selected="true"</c:if>>2</form:option>
                 <form:option value="3" <c:if test="${data.order == '3'}">selected="true"</c:if>>3</form:option>
                 <form:option value="4" <c:if test="${data.order == '4'}">selected="true"</c:if>>4</form:option>
              </form:select>
           </td>
           <td class="td-top">
               <form:select class="selectpicker form-control select-cl" path="eastCl" id="east-cl" isChanged="false">
                    <form:option value="default"> </form:option>
                    <form:option value="x" <c:if test="${data.cl == 'x'}">selected="true"</c:if>>X</form:option>
                    <form:option value="y" <c:if test="${data.cl == 'y'}">selected="true"</c:if>>Y</form:option>
                    <form:option value="w" <c:if test="${data.cl == 'z'}">selected="true"</c:if>>Z</form:option>
                    <form:option value="z" <c:if test="${data.cl == 'w'}">selected="true"</c:if>>W</form:option>
               </form:select>
           </td>
        </c:forEach>
     </tr>
```

How can i fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use EL ternary operator `${condition?'true statement':'false statement'}` insted of  `<c:if>`

like -

```
<form:select class="selectpicker form-control select-di" path="eastOrder" id="east-order" isChanged="false">
                 <form:option value="1" ${data.order =='1'? 'selected="true"' : '' }>1</form:option>
                 <form:option value="2" ${data.order =='2'? 'selected="true"' : '' }>2</form:option>
                 <form:option value="3" ${data.order =='3'? 'selected="true"' : '' }>3</form:option>
                 <form:option value="4" ${data.order =='4'? 'selected="true"' : '' }>4</form:option>
              </form:select>
```

Comment: make sure that EL is not disabled on that JSP page as well as check your web.xml if there is any disable check for EL. If still failing make sure that you are using correct ''(single comma) and " " (double comma). It matters .

Comment: This solves my problem. However, the other way doesn't work. I don't know why.


<form:option value="1" <c if test="${test.orer eq 1}">selected</c:if>>1</form:option>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solve it with :

`selected="${data.order =='1'? 'selected' : '' }"`

In your case you can do:

```
<form:select class="selectpicker form-control select-di" path="eastOrder" id="east-order" isChanged="false">
     <form:option value="1" selected="${data.order =='1'? 'selected' : '' }">1</form:option>
     <form:option value="2" selected="${data.order =='2'? 'selected' : '' }">2</form:option>
     <form:option value="3" selected="${data.order =='3'? 'selected' : '' }">3</form:option>
     <form:option value="4" selected="${data.order =='4'? 'selected' : '' }">4</form:option>
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and i solved by using  tag in  tag, use below code as reference:

you have to use this code:

with `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>`

and

```
<c:select>
            <option value="RCV"
                ${records[0].getDirection() == 'RCV' ? 'selected="true"' : ''}>
                <spring:message code="dropdown.Incoming" text="dropdown.Incoming" />
            </option>
            <option value="SND"
                ${records[0].getDirection() == 'SND'? 'selected="true"' : ''}>
                <spring:message code="dropdown.Outgoing" text="dropdown.Outgoing" />
            </option>
        </c:select>
```